# Regex: Remove the letters with length 1-3 which are before the dot

Tags: python, regex

If I have an input something like this

```
input  = 'AB. Hello word.'
the output should be 
output = 'Hello word.'
```

Another example is

```
input = 'AB′. Hello word'
output = Hello Word
```

I want to produce a code which is generalized for any group of letter in any language. This is my code

```
text = 'A. Hello word.'
text = re.sub(r'A\. \w{1,2}\.*', '', text)
text

output = llo word.
```

So I can change 'A' with any other letter, but for some reason isn't working well.

I tried also this one

```
text = 'Ab. Hello word.'
text = re.sub(r'A+\. \w{1,2}\.*', '', text)
text
output = Ab. Hello word.
```

but isn't working as well.

Comment: Do you really have `′` instead of `'` after `B` in 2nd example or that is a typo?

Comment: @anubhava yeah I have this. Isn't a typo.

Comment: In first examples where a text `word` also before dot. Why is that not getting removed?

Comment: @anubhava actually I want to remove also words/letter something like that A. AB. ABC. I changed the title. If you have any idea how to implement this by regex, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re

regex = r"^[^.]{1,3}\.\s*"

test_str = ("AB. Hello word.\n"
    "AB′. Hello word.\n"
    "A. Hello word.\n"
    "Ab. Hello word.\n")

subst = ""

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Output:

```
Hello word.
Hello word.
Hello word.
Hello word.
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nuW8HE/1)

[Rextester](https://rextester.com/KXK24873)

Comment: thank you so much! And actually your code is working in any language. Am I right? I tried it with greek letters, like α. and is working! Amazing! I would be grateful if you could explain me why we need re.MULTLINE.

Comment: [re.MULTILINE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE). This option is not needed when using a list of strings. [Rextester](https://rextester.com/DSJB44509).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regex for this, just `.split()` on it, you can just split once and take the last half `[-1]`

```py
>>> "Ab. Hello world.".split(".", 1)[-1].strip()
'Hello world.'
>>> "Hello world".split(".", 1)[-1]
'Hello world'
```

Comment: yeah I was thinking about this, but isn't working in this example. 'Ab. Hello word. A. Hello again.'.split(".", 1)[-1].strip(). The output is 'Hello word. A. Hello again.'

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex for matching:

```sh
\b[A-Za-z]{1,3}′?\.
```

Replace it with `""`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2ndjGj/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `[A-Za-z]{1,3}`: Match 1 to 3 letters
- `′?`: Match an optional `′`
- `\.`: Match a dot

Answer (score 0):

This solution may be useful:

```
a = "AB. Hello word."
print(a[a.find(".")+1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this generic regex pattern:

"^.{0,}\."

Expalination:

^  Finds a match as the beginning of a string.
.{0,} Matches any string that contains a sequence of zero or more characters.
\.  ending with a . (dot)